# Signed apk failed with error FileUsesReservedNameException

Tags: android

my app runs fine and I can build apk with no error but when I try to build signed apk it fails with this error message:
Execution failed for task ':startHulyoMainActivity:packageReleaseBundle'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/drawable-xhdpi/zooz_cards_unionpay_l.png' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.

I am using this JAR: zooz-ecomm-android-sdk-1.02.jar

How can I fix it and build the signed apk?

Comment: Issue is there `res/drawable-xhdpi/zooz_cards_unionpay_l.png`,  Try to change file name or delete this if usless

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, but zooz_cards_unionpay_l.png is not found not in the project and not even in the scope, not sure where it is coming from

Comment: change your project view from android to project and check in `drawable-xhdpi` or open file directory from file explorer

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I checked the file directory drawable-xhdpi and the png is not there. not sure where it come from

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :)

In the android studio wizard for building the signed apk in the first dialog, select the 'APK' radio button instead of the new 'Android App Bundle'. the build completed successfully.

[signed apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvzQF.png)